# Customizing error structure in Golang

Tags: go, error-handling

The default structure for error messages in golang contains a string but I want to add dynamic response code and the time the error occurred to it. Any suggestions on how to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`error` in not a struct, is an interface.

```
type error interface {
    Error() string
}
```

you can define your own error struct, just implement the `Error() string` function.

```
type ErrorA struct {
    // any field you want
}

func (e ErrorA) Error() string {
    // implement this function
}
```

then `ErrorA` can be used as `error`.

ref:
1. https://golang.org/ref/spec#Errors
2. https://golang.org/ref/spec#Interface_types

Comment: Thanks for the help.